# How to remove timestamp from datetime column in pandas Style Object

Tags: python, pandas, styles

I have a DataFrame with a Date column that has no timestamp:

[image: date without timestamp]

But once I apply `style` to another column in the df, e.g. :

```
df = df.style.applymap(colorFunction, subset=['column3'])
```

The DataFrame becomes a **Style Object**, and the **"Date"** column gets a timestamp that it didn't have before, as the following:

[image]

I tried the following to strip the timestamp from the Date column:

```
df['Date'].style.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

I got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Styler' object is not subscriptable
```

Is there any way to remove the time stamp from the Style object?

Comment: this is caused by the different formatters that DataFrame.to_html and Styler.to_html use to format dates. Use the format function as described in answer to control this precisely. This gives the Styler more flexibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a stopgap solution, but you can manually specify the usual `%Y-%m-%d` display format for your date column as follows:

```
styled = (df.style
            .applymap(colorFunction, subset=['column3'])
            .format({'Date': '{:%Y-%m-%d}'}))
```

#### Example

```
# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', 
                                         '2020-01-05', 
                                         freq='d'),
                   'Value': list(range(-2, 3))})

# Example color function
def f(v):
    return 'color: red;' if v < 0 else None

# Unexpected addition of H:M:S to date column
df.style.applymap(f, subset='Value')
```

[image: Styler with unexpected datetime display format]

```
# Specify desired date format
df.style.applymap(f, subset='Value').format({'Date': '{:%Y-%m-%d}'}))
```

[image: Styler with manually fixed datetime display format]

Comment: Many thanks @Peter Leimbigler, this gives the desired result.

Comment: @Samwise that's great to hear! Just added some example data (using pandas 1.3.2)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the good answer provided by @Peter Leimbigler, as an alternative solution, converting the Date column to a string before applying the Style prevents the Styler formatter from adding timestamp.

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
```

**Using Peter's example:**

```
# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', 
                                         '2020-01-05', 
                                         freq='d'),
                   'Value': list(range(-2, 3))})

# Example color function
def f(v):
    return 'color: red;' if v < 0 else None

# Converting the Date column to a string before applying the Style
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)

df.style.applymap(f, subset='Value')
```

[image]